# Error al buscar enlaces rotos con php con @get_headers

Tags: php, web

Lo que intento hacer es de una base de datos que contiene enlaces, correr el programa y saber que enlaces están rotos o fuera de servicio por así decirlo, sin embargo, hay algunos que me marca que están con el error de 404, sin embargo al entrar al enlace si están activados.

De igual forma, al correr el programa otra vez, aparecen otras con el error 404, y algunas que aparecían como enlaces rotos, ya no los marca como rotos.

La primera parte parca si el enlace es corto por ejemplo un https//:[www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com), sin embargo tiene la función para quitar el https//: y poder analizar de mejor forma el enlace corto, el siguiente punto son enlaces con direcciones, estos son los que presentan un fallo, ya que al momento de verificar los enlaces, a veces los marca como si estuvieran rotos, y otras veces no, por lo que quisiera preguntar como puedo solucionar eso, o si tengo algún dato que me falte, ya que si no lo marcará como 404 no entraría.

Código PHP junto HTML

```
<?php

   while ($newRow = $newResult->fetch_array()) {

   if ($newRow['longitud'] == true){
   //Enlace corto
                        
   $str = $newRow['enlace'];
   $url = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $str); 

   $site = nowww("$url");
   $check = @fsockopen($site, 80);
   $id = $newRow['id'];
   $materia = $newRow['materia'];
   $tema = $newRow['tema'];

   if (!$check) {
   echo "
         <div class='col-8'>
          <span id='$id'>El enlace $id de la materia $materia del tema $tema.</span>
          <h6>$site</h6>
         </div>

         $error = $error + 1;
      ";
    }

    //Enlace largo
    }else{

    $file = $newRow['enlace'];
    $id = $newRow['id'];
    $materia = $newRow['materia'];
    $tema = $newRow['tema'];

    $file_headers = @get_headers($file);
    if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
      $exists = false;
      echo "
           <div class='col-8'>
             <span id='$id'>El enlace $id de la materia $materia del tema $tema.</span>
             $file
           </div>";
      $error = $error + 1;
     }
   }
 }
 if($error == 0){
 echo "<script>document.getElementById('$materiaID').style.display='none';</script>";
 }
 echo "
  
</div>
 
<!--END: Table-->

</div>
</div>
</div>
              ";
              $index = $index + 1;

              echo "<script>document.getElementById('$materiaText').innerHTML='$error';</script>";
            }
          }


        if($index == 0){
            $varResult = "No hay enlaces rotos. ";
            echo "
            <tr>
              <td style='width: 80%;'>
                <label>$varResult</label>
                $varBack
              </td>
            </tr>
            ";

          }



          //Liberas el resultado
          mysqli_free_result($result);


          //Cerras coneccion
          mysqli_close($link);

         function nowww($text) {
         $word = array(
         "http://" => "",
         "www." => "",
         );
         foreach ($word as $bad => $good) {
         $text = str_replace($bad, $good, $text);
         }
         $oldurl = explode("/", $text);
         $newurl = $oldurl[0];
         $text = "$newurl";
         $text = strip_tags(addslashes($text));
         return $text;
         }

         ?>
```